# Nuxt 3 useHead: how to replace body class instead of adding to it?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

I'm working on a Nuxt 3 project, and I want to **replace** the body class on route change using the useHead hook. Specifically, I want to use useFetch to load data for the current page, and once that data is resolved, I want to use data.bodyclass to replace the body class of the document.

Here's what I use:

```
useHead({
     bodyAttrs: { class: `page--${data.bodyClass}` 
});
```

The problem with this code is that it **adds** data.bodyclass to the existing body class, rather than replacing it. What's the best way to replace the body class using useHead in this scenario?

After changing route the body looks like
`<body class='class-loaded-for-page-1 class-loaded-for-page-2'>`  but I want it result in `<body class='class-loaded-for-page-2'>`

I can't use vanilla `document.body.classlist` to modify the class-attribute as i use SSR where document is not defined.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the reasons is your code is incorrect. You are missing an end curly bracket inside the `useHead` composable.

```js
// Incorrect
useHead({
     bodyAttrs: { class: `page--${data.bodyClass}` 
});

// Correct
useHead({
    bodyAttrs: {
        class: `page--${home.value}`
    }
})
```

Try fixing that and it should be working. I made an example and it works
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/intelligent-hermann-59ifef

Inspect element the code. Make sure you are inspecting the correct body tag. It should be inside an `iframe`
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your extensive reply. The missing curly bracket was due to the fact that I minified my code to this minimal version. The rest of my code would be irrelevant for the example.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in the place **where** useHead was called.
As many pages use the same code for querying an api I created a plugin that fetches from the API. So the scripts in all pages only needed `await $loadPageFromApi(*slug*)`.
In this plugin function I called *useHead* before returning the fetched data. That resulted in the classes to be added instead of replaced.
Thanks to the example of @ReaganM I tried calling *useHead()* in the page's scripts which actually replaced the class.

Answer (score 0):

I do get the same issue too. But I found out that what you need to do is turn the class name into object with boolean value to make it toggleable. Like this

```js
let isDarkTheme = ref(true)

useHead({
  bodyAttrs: {
    class: {
      "theme-dark": isDarkTheme.value
    }
  }
});
```

based on this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/vueuse/head/issues/55)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with style attribute, I just used `document.body`:

```js
if (process.client) {
  document.body.style = style
} else {
  useHead({ bodyAttrs: { style } })
}
```

You can do the same with class using: `document.body.className`, and manipulate classes directly. Also maybe simpler with `document.body.classList`.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to set `id` for the head element:

```
  useHead({
         bodyAttrs: { 
           id:"your-id-goes-here",
           class: `page--${data.bodyClass}` 
    });
```

Comment: This will not make it replace the class